# Foreign key references itself

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, pdo, schema

I want to create a table for categories where if the `parent_id` is 0, then that category has no parent. Otherwise, any category can be the parent of another category:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  cat_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY(cat_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES categories(cat_id)
);
```

The problem upon trying to insert a new value is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`cat_id`))

I assume this means that a `parent_id` cannot be 0, because no `cat_id` with that value exists. How can I get around this issue or better design my table?

Comment: Try to use NULL as the parent_id instead of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the table so the parent_id can be `NULL` and use `NULL` instead of `0` to represent top-level categories.

```
ALTER TABLE categories
  MODIFY COLUMN parent_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: I want to select record from this kind of table, but my table named as Employee and foreign key is ManagerId which is referenced with Employee Table's EmpId . And I want to get record with manager's name also . How it is possible.